# Integer to date php

Tags: php, date

I have three integers containing date, month and year. I want to convert it to date format.

```
$date = 20;
$month = 8;
$year = 1989;
```

I have applied the below formula, but when I echo $mydate, it shows `08-08-1990`

```
$mydate = date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,$date,$month,$year));
```

I can not find where I am making the mistake!

Comment: Answer is given, but you should read documentation of Function argument before using them :).

Comment: `echo (new DateTime)->setDate(1989, 8, 20)->format('d-m-Y');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `month` and `day` places reverse

```
$mydate = date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$date,$year));
```

#### Output

```
20-08-1989
```

**mktime syntax** `mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year)`

Answer (score 3):

It will be like

```
$mydate = date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$date,$year));
```

`mktime()` will take them like

```
mktime(hours,minutes,seconds,month,day,year);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it like

```
$mydate = date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$date,$year));
```

mktime syntax is: **mktime(hours,minutes,seconds,month,day,year);**

Answer (score 1):

mktime will do it for you !

```
 $date = date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$date,$year));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtotime function.

e.g.

```
echo $a=strtotime("2009-03-18");
echo "<br />";
echo date("Y-m-d",$a);
```

Answer (score 1):

do it like this, it may help you

```
$originalDate = $year."-".$month."-".$date;
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate;
```